# User activity monitoring open source software

Tags: windows, macos, logging

I was wondering if there is open source project similar to this commercial product [SpectorPro](http://www.codework-systems.com/products/spectorsoft/spector-pro/).

I have been using it for some time now and I love how I can view all my activity as I would history in my browser. I'm not crazy about the screen shots just the capture of typing as means of backup in case my system crashes. And also the sneakiness is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[KidLogger](http://kidlogger.net/) if you're on windows or Mac.