# Software for logging all user's actions on Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, logging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User activity monitoring open source software](https://superuser.com/questions/284006/user-activity-monitoring-open-source-software)

I currently have a windows 7 machine, with one password protected administrator account, and one simple user account.

Is there any software that logs all user's actions so the administrator can see what has the other user typed, which programs has opened etc. (not in real time, files preferred)?

Comment: There are several options for this but you should be warned. Almost all options that do what you are asking for impact system performance greatly.

Comment: assuming the user only browses the internet, rerely uses IM and maybe downloads some files...that should not be such an overhead.

Comment: @develroot If we are only talking about internet use, you can log all traffic on your router.

Comment: @iglvzx yeah, and then parse all the tcp packets on port 80 to get google searches and other accessed websites?

Comment: For web tracking: [How to track websites that have been visited?](http://superuser.com/questions/52181/how-to-track-websites-that-have-been-visited)

Comment: I had feared this would have turned into Yet Another Privacy Question.